# Pop-up message after submitting a form with php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get a pop-up message saying if it was successfully submitted or not without having to go to a different page.

Now chrome gives me the pop-up message but it redirects me to a blank page after.

Here is my current code.

```
<?php
include "header.php";
include "conexao.php";
echo "<h1 align='center'>Pagina para alterar produtos</h1><div class='container'><hr>";
$referencia=$_GET['id'];


$sql = "SELECT * ";
        $sql = $sql . " FROM tb_produto ";
        $sql = $sql . " WHERE pr_codigo='".$referencia."'";
        $produtos = $db->query($sql);
        foreach ($produtos as $produto) {
            $referencia = $produto["pr_codigo"];
            $nome = $produto["pr_descricao"];
            $preco = $produto["pr_preco"];
            $disponivel = $produto["disponivel"];
        }
        echo "<h2>Referencia: ".$referencia."</h2>";
        echo "<h2>Nome: ".$nome."</h2><hr>";

?>
<form action="confirmaAlterar.php">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Referencia</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="referencia" value="<?php echo $referencia?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Nome</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Preço</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="preco" value="<?php echo $preco?>">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</button>
</form>
```

Here is where it submits the information of the form.

```
<?php
include "header.php";
include "conexao.php";
$nome=$_GET['nome'];
$referencia=$_GET['referencia'];
$preco=$_GET['preco'];
$sql="UPDATE tb_produto SET pr_descricao='".$nome;
$sql.="', pr_preco=".$preco;
$sql.= " WHERE pr_codigo='".$
try{
    $comando=$db->prepare($sql);
    $comando->execute();
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
    header( "refresh2;Location:index.php" );
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "A";
}
```

Comment: You need to submit form using ajax if you don't want page to reload

Comment: or redirect on url pass message in url and show it on request variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass values using ajax. Form:

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" value="test" name="akcija"> 
</form>
```

All inputs fields values in your form will be passed.

Ajax:

```
jQuery(function(){
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) { //on submit function
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post', //method POST
      url: 'yoururl.php', //URL of page where u place query and passing values
      data: $('#form').serialize(), //seriallize is passing all inputs values of form
      success: function(){ //on success function
              $("#input").attr("disabled", true); //example
              $("#input").removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');//example
                  },
    });
}
});
```

And on the ajax page you can get values by

```
$akcija = $_POST['akcija']
```

Comment: Please don't post Javascript code that depends on jQuery when there is no jQuery tag on the question.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois just wanted to help, should i remove answer.. or ?

Comment: Update the answer to only use plain javascript, then it's fine.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, please, don't recomend to edit useful answer your way - write own one.

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic should i "id" all inputs or there's one in special

Comment: @BrunoReis Actually you don't need id for form submitting. All input fields will be passed no matter they have id, You need name tag so you can access value of the input field on the ajax page using 
$akcija  = $_POST['akcija']

Answer (score 0):

for this Problem you must use ajax method .

1- create html form and all input Required .

```
<form id="contactForm2" action="/your_url" method="post">
...
</form>
```

2- add jQuery library file in the head of html page .

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">       
</script>
...
```

3- add this method Under the jQuery library

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var frm = $('#contactForm2');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
           if(data == 'pass')
            alert('ok');
           else(data == 'fail')
            alert('no');
        }
    });

    ev.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

4- in your_url  .php file

```
<?php 

  $a = ok ;
  if( $a == 'ok' ){
    echo 'pass';
  }else{
    echo 'fail';
  } 

?>
```

this top answer is easy management form with jquery , but you need managment Complex form better use this library http://jquery.malsup.com/form/